# set value to conditionally disabled dropdown

Tags: javascript

i have two drop downs,for certain value the other dropdown gets disabled,for which i used javascript.But problem is when it gets disabled my "required field validation"gets invoked.How to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to disable the validator for the dropdown like this:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= ValidatorID.ClientID %>'), false);
```

Comment: @M Nitin Kumar Is this what you were looking for, if so please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Otherwse, please provide more information regarding what you are wanting to do.